# Setting additional point attributes in HighStock time series with large data sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I know you can pass arbitrary data into your time series points, such as:

```
new Highcharts.Chart( {
   ...,
   series: [{
         name: 'Foo',
         data: [ { y : 10.0, customData : 'value 1' },
                 { y : 20.0, customData : 'value 2' },
                 { y : 30.0, customData : 'value 3' } ]
      }]
} );
```

However, I noticed that this doesn't quite work in HighStock when your time series is comprised of a large data set (1000+ points).

For example, here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gparajon/c5fej775/ (less than 1000 points, which also happens to be the default turboThreshold). And here's the same fiddle, with more data, which breaks the tooltip formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/gparajon/5om258az/

Any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the console is a [bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5922) and it is not really connect why you cannot access extra info in the formatter.

The difference between a chart and a stockchart is that a stockchart does data grouping, what means that in the formatter callback you receive grouped points which does not include extra data (how should they be grouped?).

example: https://jsfiddle.net/g04La2qh/1/

If you disable data grouping, you will receive non-grouped points with extra data.

```
dataGrouping: {
    enabled: false
  },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/g04La2qh/2/

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for. I found this note after the fact: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping